# How do I manipulate a menu in the View from the controller in Asp.net MVC 5?

Tags: kendo-ui, asp.net-mvc-5, kendo-asp.net-mvc

The gist of my problem is to change the menu of my website to show the logged in user and a logout button where there was a login button from the start. 
I'm new to MVC and might be going about this all wrong. this is the menu I wish to alter, and you'll see what my idea was. in Forms I could easily access this from the code behind and make one of the two menu options non visible.

```
<ul id="menu">
                        <li>@Html.ActionLink("Home", "Index", "Home")</li>
                        <li>@Html.ActionLink("Members", "About", "Home")</li>
                        <li>@Html.ActionLink("Schedule", "Contact", "Home")</li>
                        <li id="loginLink">@Html.ActionLink("Login", "Login", "Account")</li>
                        <li id="logoutLink">@Html.ActionLink("(" + Session["userName"].ToString() + ")" + "Logout", "Logout", "Account")</li>
                    </ul>
```

Comment: Let me know if my solution did not work for you...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why would you want to do View manipulation from the controller?  I believe that View specific logic should sit in the View itself.

If you have authenticated the user, and set the authentication cookie, you could just do the following in your view:

```
<ul id="menu">
  <li>@Html.ActionLink("Home", "Index", "Home")</li>
  <li>@Html.ActionLink("Members", "About", "Home")</li>
  <li>@Html.ActionLink("Schedule", "Contact", "Home")</li>
  @if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
  {
      <li id="LogoutLink">@Html.ActionLink(User.Identity.Name + "Log Out", "Logout", "Account")</li>
  }
  else
  {
      <li id="loginLink">@Html.ActionLink("Login", "Login", "Account")</li>
  }
</ul>
```

Without knowing exactly how you authenticate your user, I cannot say for sure that this solution will suit your needs.

This example will return the LogoutLink List Item if the user is Authenticated, otherwise, it will return the LoginLink List Item if the user is not authenticated.

In case you are interested in using the ASP.NET Identity library for authentication, [here](http://benfoster.io/blog/aspnet-identity-stripped-bare-mvc-part-1) is a blog with some brilliant examples, this has helped me a lot.

Comment: hmm, I have not used User.Identity. I could not figure out how to actually set it, I use Session variable instead, is the Identity recommended in MVC?

Comment: Well, if you set the cookie, there will be no need for you to store these information in the session, which I think is a bad practice. How are you currently authenticating your users?

Comment: I have updated my answer to include the following link on using the ASP.Net Identity library, if you are interested.
http://benfoster.io/blog/aspnet-identity-stripped-bare-mvc-part-1

Comment: I just match the password stored in the database with the supplied password in the login screen, hashed ofc.

Comment: Give the post I supplied you with a read, especially part one, it will explain the minimum required to implement this. You do not have to change  your current way of authentication, you do not have to use Entity Framework, just give it a read, and see if it will suit your needs. Otherwise, if you do not feel like doing this, just check your Session in the if statement, and apply the correct button based on the if condition, but this is not recommended.

Comment: Thank you, I will give it a read, I wanted to implement Identity from the start. :)

Comment: One last question, in the guide you linked, they use OwinContext to get the authentication object. should I use Owin with my type of authentication?

Comment: No, you are not forced to use OWIN. There are different ways handling authentication, this is just one of them, and probably the most popular at the moment. If you need any help setting up, maybe we can take this to a personal chat?

Comment: It failed to automatically move the discussion to chat. the only reason I asked if I needed Owin is that I was advised against owin since I have this simple authentication and didn't need to connect facebook etc. accounts to my site.

Comment: Whoever told you that, must have probably been referring to OAuth authentication, that is the process of authenticating with third party software.  Chat failed on my side as well

Comment: Ah okay. yeah there was both OAuth and Owin involved in his project. so I'll be using this guide as it is and use Owin :)

Comment: I could use some help with Owin, I followed the guide part 1, I used the SignIn method in the IAuthenticationManager from the OwinContext. but yet after that the isAuthenticated flag is still false.

Comment: Okay, I can help you, you just need to give me a half an hour or so. DO you perhaps have some personal platform we can message on, I do not see the personal chat option on here now.

Comment: hmm, I have Skype, facebook and skype for business. whichever works for me, although I'm not sure how to talk with people outside of our exchange network.

Comment: Do you have gmail chat?